# Update Mongodb Object in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I can't figure out why this doesn't work. I've seen many examples where it does. All I want to do is add to an existing object in Mongo.

Current object

```
{ _id: 53951f43f6000e954d29f8e3,
  username: 'upload1',
  __v: 0 }
```

I'd like to add to this object, so it looks like this:

```
{ _id: 53951f43f6000e954d29f8e3,
  username: 'upload1',
  images: ['path/to/img', 'path/to/img'],
  __v: 0 }
```

I'm using Express, and this is what my code looks like:

```
User.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function (err, user) {
  // catch error
  user.images = ['path/to/img', 'path/to/img']
  user.save(function (err) {
    // catch error
  })
})
```

I've also attempted `User.update()`, `User.findAndUpdate()`, `{upset: true}`, and nothing works... :\

Any ideas on whats going on here? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I could ask if your model has the field defined, but must likely your problem is the string for `_id`. Cast as an ObjectId or use the `.findById()` or `.findByIdAndUpdate()` methods.

Comment: Wow. Epic fail on my part. I did not have images defined in my model... thanks for pointing that out. If you want to answer, I will mark it as answered

Comment: Doesn't matter really. But also note the casing is important for methods such as `.findOne()` and others using a query object. The other noted methods will cast your input string for you.

Comment: @NeilLunn Actually, Mongoose does the casting to ObjectId for you in a `findOne` or `find` as well (based on the schema).